# On share intent list there is no my app on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

When I display a photo in gallery and click share icon, as for example in this screen:

[image: pic]

I'd like to have my app appearing on this list. It works for my device with Ice Cream, however it doesn't work for a device with Lollipop.

My intent-filters in AndroidManifest look like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `android:name="com.test">` That should be more like android:name="com.test.MyActivity">

Comment: You might try this intent: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO

Comment: R. Zagórski - that worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually now I think that android.intent.action.SEND was enough, but because of Android Studio's Instant Run I couldn't notice any difference. I had to build an app once again to notice it. Thank you all!